# Where to find reliable snowfall rate data?

Tags: hydrology, precipitation, earth-observation, snow, weatherdata

Would you please let me know where I can find/download reliable snowfall rate datasets?

I am looking for multiple weather stations (in different regions) or field measured data, that contain both solid/liquid precipitation data.

Thank you.

Comment: you can do a search for hydrology and see what you can find,where i live we have this site dedicated to show water in all its forms http://www.senorge.no/aboutXgeo.html  it is in norwegian so it will probably not be very helpfull but it can give you an idea of what to look for,if you are lucky you can find something simmilar for your area.

Comment: Here is snowview https://climate.arizona.edu/snowview/main/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you want may not be actually available. [It is standard to make measurements of snow every 24 hours.](https://www.weather.gov/media/coop/Snow_Measurement_Guidelines-2014.pdf) This is because it is well known that [frequent observations of snowfall will exceed the total accumulated snowfall.](http://www.lakecountyskywarn.org/education/guides/snowfall.html)

The total accumulation of snow is not equal to the sum of the accumulated rate of the integral. That is, $$\Delta S \ne\int_{t_0}^{t_1}Rdt$$ where $\Delta S$ is the change in snow depth and $R$ is the snowfall rate. This is because compaction and melting both occur, changing snow depth.

That being said, you can make an approximation using daily snowfall depth observations. In the U.S., there are two systems that spring to mind. The first is the [U.S. Cooperative Observation Program](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/COOP/), which uses the standard in-situ observations of snow depth. The second is the NOHRSC, which has an analysis product (use [this link](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/) for archived numerical data or [this link](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/interactive/html/map.html?var=snowfall_24_h&snap=1&bgvar=dem&shdvar=shading&o9=1&o13=1) for a graphical product).